# How to install a compiler on Windows? (For a Matlab program)

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I have downloaded this code;

http://www.cs.sfu.ca/%7Emori/research/superpixels/superpixels64.tar.gz

In the readme file, it says;

- Run mex -largeArrayDims on *.c in yu_imncut directory
  -largeArrayDims is needed for 64bit architectures (thanks to Richard Lowe for providing fixes for 64bit MATLAB)
- Obtain mfm-pb boundary detector code from 
  http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/projects/vision/grouping/segbench/
- Change path names in sp_demo.m and pbWrapper.m
- Get a fast processor and lots of RAM
- Run sp_demo.m

I tried to do the mex -.. one but it told me that I don't have any compiler. How can I fix this? Can you please help me with this? I am using 64 bit Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to GCC for windows
http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html#windows

Comment: Thank you I downloaded this http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-snapshot/mingw-w64-v1.0-snapshot-20110428.tar.bz2/download  but I actually don't know what to do with it. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know GCC for Windows is not supported by Matlab. Visual Studio Express Editions will work, but 2010 may require a patch dependent on the version of Matlab you are running (http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011a/win32.html). This page lists all supported compilers for Matlab.

Comment: That list is several years old. Here's the new one. http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/index.html;jsessionid=c4e9f738b6203e148aa5176f72e7 OP probably wants the "Windows 7.1 SDK" which is basically a free compiler that Microsoft is giving out now.