# How to use 'gmake install' on Windows?

Tags: matlab, gnu-make

I downloaded a matlab code from on my Windows 7 64 bit, using R2010a

http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/segbench/code/segbench.tar.gz

It says

(2) Run 'gmake install' from this directory to build everything.  You
should then probably put the lib/matlab directory in your MATLAB path.

How can I do this on Windows? I have Cygwin but apperantly it doesnt have it. Can't I run this code on Windows? I don't get it. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Oh. I just noticed that you have three related questions. In the future, it would be best if you referenced your other posts in your question so that we aren't all reinventing the wheel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861605 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861891

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSYS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) is a native port of `make`,`gcc` and other *NIX GNU utilities for Windows.   Try installing MSYS and running `make` from there.

Unfortunately, the MSYS documentation is not always super clear or always up to date. Download the install from the [SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/).

Note also that when you run `make install` it usually means you are actually running a makefile to compile source code (often `C`). This means that, if the `C` code relies on libraries or dependencies that you don't have on Windows, you may be out of luck anyway. Hopefully this isn't the case for you.

Good luck.